# Can we use Gson library to parse JSON on regular class?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I was wondering if I could use the Gson library with a regular class instead of a `dataclass` ?

Here is my json:

```
val json = """
{
   "name": "Alex",
   "address": {
        "city": "Rome",
        "post": "1000"
    }
 }
```

And my code :

```
data class Address(
    var city: String? = null,
    var post: String? = null) {

}

data class Student(
    var name: String? = null,
    var address: Address? = null) {
}
// Call
val student = Gson().fromJson<Student>(json, Student::class.java)
// student.address.city will be = "Rome"
```

I couldn't find an example with the regular class.
The problem is that I have to use those data classes in multiple files and I would like to avoid to write them in every file.

So is it possible to use Gson with a regular class?
Or can I create a global `dataclass`?

Comment: You shouldn't write those data classes in "every" file. Just have two separate data classes (separate files) and use them from wherever you want, as you said "globally".

Answer (score 0):

Try to create those classes in separate file and use them anywhere it required.

**Address.kt**

```
class Address(
    var city: String? = null,
    var post: String? = null) {

}
```

**Student.kt**

```
class Student(
    var name: String? = null,
    var address: Address? = null) {
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ....

        val student = Gson().fromJson<Student>(json, Student::class.java)
    }
}
```

**OtherActivity.kt**

```
class OtherActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ....

        val student = Gson().fromJson<Student>(json, Student::class.java)
    }
}
```

**JsonUtil.kt**

```
class JsonUtil {
    fun parseJson(json: String?) {
        val student = Gson().fromJson<Student>(json, Student::class.java)
    }
}
```